# Steganography in DCT vs DWT

Tags: steganography

I have to do a steganography based project and I'm a bit confused to do it using DCT or DWT..Any one please help to decide...what the advantages and disadvantage using either one and which one I should use and why?

Comment: What are your intentions? Do you have a specific algorithm in mind? Are you going to use jpeg images? Without specific information, in vacuum, this can be a pretty broad question.

Comment: I don't have any algorithm in mind.will select on the base of method and yes i going to use JPEG

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. DWT or DCT as a method must be in context of that. Regardless, if you're going to use jpeg, chances are DCT is going to be involved anyway. For example, the simplest algorithm would be to follow the jpeg encoding process (split image in 8x8, DCT each block, quantise coefficients) and then apply your steganography algorithm on those integer coefficients as if they are pixels. Then carry on with the jpeg encoding by saving those coefficients in a jpeg format.

Comment: Can't we use DWT on JPEG instead of DCT ??? and i want to know there advantages and disadvantages in stenography.on those points i would like to choose...

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you can use it. But whether it will work depends on how you will use it. How will that be? And how do we qualify what is an advantage or disadvantage? What is your aim? Robustness? Imperceptibility? Capacity? Something else?

Comment: told you will decide method and it's algorithm on there points..for now,I'm not searching for a specific point..it would be great if you could provide details based on all points